# Python sub folder modules not able to import other subfolder modules

Tags: python-3.x, import

I have been struggling to figure out how to organize my code effectively with many modules of various types. I have a three layered folder system. The parent directory contains the main.py file which imports and runs the main code. The modules are in a subfolder called lib, and different modules are placed in further subfolders. However, when I import one module from a subfolder, that module itself fails to import modules in the same sub directory. Sorry if this is a bad question, but I cannot figure out why the import statement isn't working, and I have looked at google and stack overflow and have not found any similar problem. All advice is welcome.

```
Parent Directory
---->lib
      |--->module_group
            |module_one.py(that tries but fails to import module_one)
            |module_two.py
 |main.py
```

In main I run

```
from lib.module_group.module_one import Module_One
```

Which works until an error is handled saying that there is no such module as module two. However, when I run module_one by itself, it works fine with the following import statement.

```
from module_two import Module_Two
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `PYTHONPATH` to the directory you want to act as your root. For example, if you want to use the following code:

```
from lib.module_group.module_one import Module_One
```

Then set `PYTHONPATH` to the directorying containing `lib`. For example:

`lib/module_group/module_one.py`:

```
from lib.module_group.module_two import Module_Two
```

`lib/module_group/module_two.py`:

```
class Module_Two:
    print('Loaded Module_Two')
```

Then, to run `module_one.py` directly and still enable it to use `lib.module_group.module_two` to load `Module_Two`, use something like:

```
$ PYTHONPATH="${PWD}:${PYTHONPATH}" python3 lib/module_group/module_one.py
Loaded Module_Two
```